# Import 2 Excel Files via SSIS with different sheet names

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

So as the title suggest, I need to do an import of 2 Excel (.xlsx) files from my local machine (c:\temp) into one SQL Server table. Each of the files only contains one sheet, but the sheet names will differ. The columnnames and no of columns on each file is identical.

If I select one specific excel file through SSIS via Excel Connection Manager, it extracts the data perfectly and inserts it into my destination SQL table.

The problem comes in when I add a ForEach Loop Container and want to loop through the c:\temp directory to read the 2 files. Somewhere I am missing a setting and keep getting various "connect to Excel" errors.

Please assist with the following:

I am unsure how to specify the Excel file path. Is the below correct? I used to select the exact file here when loading only 1 file:

[image]

Then it seems I need to create variables, so I did below:
[image]

Then I am not sure if I should add an expression to my ForEach loop and which mappings would be correct?

[image]
[image]

And lastly, I am not sure whether to put the filename or sheetname as variable below. I tried the filepath, but get the following error:

[image]

Please help as I am totally lost with this.

### UPDATE

OK, I have now done the following:

Added a SheetName variable (which I think the Value is maybe incorrect). I am trying to tell it to only read the first sheet.

[image]

Then my Excel connection string looks like this:
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=NO";

[image]

My ForEach loop:
[image]

And my Excel source:
[image]

I get the following error:
[Book [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u20M9.png)] Error: Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

Comment: Having the Table/View as the variable `User::Directory` seems wrong; if you are storing the worksheet's name in a variable, the `Directory` seems an odd choice of name for said variable. Seems like you are looking at the wrong variable, and should be using your `SheetName` variable

Comment: Ok Thanks. So I created a Filename variable. Do I need to specify an Excel ConnectionManager if I want to loop through excel files? If I create one, I cannot seem to specify a directory name, only a file name.

Comment: The Excel Source Connection Manager needs a filepath, not a file name or directory. The Source then needs to know what Manager to use, and what Worksheet or Query to use.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have updated my original post with things I have changed. Now getting error:  Error: Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your biggest issue is in regards to getting the sheetname which can vary, and the only way I know how to do this is with a script task.

So inside your foreach loop (store filepath to the Excel file) as variable, add a script task before you enter the data flow.

First of all start with knowing you connection string (I use this site for help: https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Set your read/write variable to [SheetName] and read to FilePath

Code:

```
var cstr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = YES"";"
                 , Dts.Variables["FilePath"].ToString()); //Enter your connection string for OleDB conn
    
using (var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cstr))
{
      conn.Open();
      var sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    
      //Since there is only 1 for sure.
      Dts.Variables["SheetName"] = sheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
}
```

Now you have the SheetName in a variable (this will have the $ in the sheetname that you need as well), set up another variable called SQL and define it as `"Select * from [" + SheetName + "]"`.

Now use the variable SQL in your DataFlow Source.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I am convinced that would work. Currently my connection string is Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=NO"; I think HDR should be YES? The edit box is checked so its strange.

Comment: Data Source is not there in your connection string. that is where full file path goes.

Comment: HDR defines if there is a header row.

Comment: I am trying to follow your instructions but it seems I am not even able to add a Script Task to the data flow, it seems only available in the control flow. I would really appreciate if you could by any chance, add a screenshot or 2 for the instructions.

Comment: Correct. you are adding the script task to the foeach loop container.

Comment: The only thing you are changing in your current data flow is in the Excel Source. You are changing the source to use the SQL variable.

Comment: Thanks Keith, does this look correct for the script?

Comment: public void Main()
  {
            var cstr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\temp;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = YES"";"
                 , Dts.Variables["FilePath"].ToString()); 

            using (var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cstr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

  Dts.Variables["SheetName"] = sheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            }
  Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
 }

Comment: giving me an error in scriptmain.cs:
Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0200 Property or indexer 'Variables.this[object]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only ST_2820cba9b8c748c2831118743b9d7ceb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248910/discussion-between-pierre-barnard-and-keithl).